# What is meant by bite and consume one another?

Tags: law, galatians

Gal5:14 For all the law is fulfilled in one word, even in this: “You shall love your neighbor as yourself.” 15 But if you bite and devour one another, beware lest you be consumed by one another!

Obviously verse 15 is not referring to cannibalism, yet this analogy is used in contrast to fulfilling the law.

Is there a Hebraic understanding to this concept, that can be illustrated through scripture?

Answer (score 1):

It is being used in contrast to one particular law, not so much "the law", that is: "You shall love your neighbor as yourself."

Now there was a problem at the Galatian assemblies. After Paul's visit, Jewish-Christian missionaries arrived with instructions to be circumcised.

Word got back to Paul and he explained why this was not necessary for Gentile converts.

Paul here is asking them not to let this question get out of hand and cause conflicts.

Now Paul was absolutely furious and he might be projecting his own fury back on the situation in the churches. True, this does not have to do with cannibalism, but more to do with the vicious struggles animals can have.

He was so infuriated that he wished castration on his opponents.

5:12 Would that those who are upsetting you might also get themselves castrated.

So as you can see, the mood was not light. He was afraid that the members could very well turn on each other. If any of them got as upset as he was, there would be sparks flying.

According to Dunn (commentary on Galations) a commentary by H. D. Betz (Galatians, Hermeneia, Philadelphia: Fortress Press, 1979) points out that: "Comparisons of bad conduct with the behaviour of wild animals were a commonplace in the diatribe literature." (Betz 276-277)

It is a commonplace from secular literature.